# how to export more column records in excel when click on view report in ssrs?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I want to show limited columns(10 columns) initially while rendering report output and after selecting excel export option ,click on view report then i need to export more columns records (40 columns data) in excel output.anyone give an idea to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the columns you want to hide and setup Column Visibility as "Show or hide based on condition" and setup below expression as condition.

```
=Iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

Comment: I think the True and False are switched.  This expression will hide columns when rendering to Excel and show them in all other renderers.